# Enter File Name When Executing Program In C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm learning *C++*, then i was searching for some codes for learn something in the area that i love: *File I/O*, but i want to know how i can tweak my code for the user type the file that he wants to see, like in *wget*, but with my program like this:

```
C:\> FileSize test.txt
```

The code of my program is here:

```
// obtaining file size
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  long begin,end;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.close();
  cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I realize that Stackoverflow is open to everyone so it will be a free exchange of information, but you ask quite a few questions that a simple google search would answer.

Comment: I've searched in Google before!

Comment: Suggest you use stat function to get the file size in this case.  It fills in a "struct stat" if successful and you can then st_size to to check the value of the file size.  The code above has no checking if the file doesn't exist.  Anyhow, just being picky... the point is open a file name passed in from the command line :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example below argv contains command line arguments as null terminated string array and argc contains an integer telling you how many arguments where passed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
  long begin,end;
  if( argc < 2 )
  {
     cout << "No file was passed. Usage: myprog.exe filetotest.txt";
     return 1;
  }

  ifstream myfile ( argv[1] );
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.close();
  cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That should be ifstream myfile ( argv[1] );
As argv[0] contains the name of the executable file.

Comment: Woops should be argv[1] not argv[0]

Comment: But when i type a file or don't type the message of the program is every: size is: 0  bytes. **Whats worong?**

Comment: The `argc` check is wrong.  `argc==1` is no arguments, `argc>=2` is at least 1 argument.

Comment: Ahh yes that should be updated as well, I'll edit the post to reflect the corrections.

Comment: It's still wrong.  You probably mean `if (argc < 2)`, not `if (argc >= 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

`main()` takes parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    ifstream myfile (argv[1]);
    ...
}
```

You could also get clever, and loop for each file specified on the command line:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int file = 1; file < argc;  file++) {
        ...
        ifstream myfile (argv[file]);
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that argv[0] is a string pointing to the name of your own program.

Comment: Minor spelling mistake "args[1]" should be "argv[0]"

Answer (score 1):

Main takes two arguments, which you can use to do this. See this:

[Uni ref](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html)

[MSDN reference (has VC specific commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx)